# Unable to download Android SDK from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, xamarin, tls1.2, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to download Android SDK on Visual Studio 2019, but I'm getting an error. When I take a look at sdkmanager.log file, I see `System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.` error.

[image]

I've tried disabling virus guard, disabling firewall, and repairing visual studio. Nothing worked.

I've attached both [ide.log](https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/464326ff) file and [sdkmanager.log](https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/d001b64c) files.

Comment: Try Android Studio ( https://developer.android.com/studio/ ) , if successful you can point the Visual Studio Android SDK installation directory at the one Android Studio made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this
Have to disable Tls1.3

Thanks for these 2 guys
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gGAAnn3acU
https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/7705